# Is the infimum of the product of the coordinates of a lattice positive?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, products, integer-lattices

Let $L \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a lattice of rank $2$. Consider the set
$$A := \{ x_1x_2 : x \in L \}.$$
Is the infimum of $A \cap (0,\infty)$ always positive?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out myself. The answer is: The infimum is **not** always positive.

We give an example: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ be an irrational number with approximation exponent $\sigma>2$. This means that the inequality
$$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| < q^{-\sigma}$$
has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb Z$. Without loss of generality we even have
$$0<\alpha - \frac{p}{q}< q^{-\sigma}$$
for arbitrary large $q$.

We define the lattice
$$L := \left\{\binom{\alpha q-p}{q} : p,q \in \mathbb Z \right\}.$$
Then we have
$$ 0 < (\alpha q-p)q = q^2 \left( \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right) < q^{2-\sigma}$$
for arbitrary large $q$. So the product of the coordinates gets arbitrary small.